# Passing 2D array into GLES opengl shader

Tags: android, arrays, opengl-es

I have a 2D array of floats (in this case it represents a 256 color palette with R G B values)

```
static float[][] glColorPaletteArray = new float[256][3];
```

I fill the array and now want to pass it to GLES.  How do I pass a 2D array in android?  I try

```
GLES20.glUniform3fv(paletteLoc,256,glColorPaletteArray,0);
```

but it complains about expecting a 1D array (found float[][] expecting float[]).

The shader is expecting a vec3 uniform, ie

```
uniform vec3 palette[256];
```

so I need to keep the 2D array so the RGB components are separate floats.

What is the secret to getting the 2D array passed correctly to the GLES shader so I can then access the RGB values in the shader by using

```
int red = palette[100].r;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: You cannot pass a 2D array to a shader.

In order to pass a 2D array to OpenGL, one has to flatten the array. This is relatively easy and can, e.g., be done as follows:

```
static float[][] glColorPaletteArray = new float[256][3];
static float[] openglArray = new float[256*3];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        openglArray[i * 3 + j] = glColorPalletArray[i][j];
```

But I would suggest that, if possible, you define the array in 1D at first hand.

Comment: OK, but once converted to 1D will the shader (expecting vec3 entries) know how to extract the RGB components of each of the 256 colors?

Comment: Yes it will. Always 3 consecutive floats will be used as one vec3.